# Creating a hana::set from template parameter pack

Tags: c++, boost-hana

I'm struggling to figure out how to make a hana::set from a template parameter pack. I have a method that I have used for tuples (tuple_t) but it seems to create a set I have to use make_set. Here is where I'm getting stuck:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
class Foo
{
public:
    static constexpr auto asTuple = hana::tuple_t<Ts...>;
    static constexpr auto asSet = hana::make_set(/*what goes here?*/);
};
```

Thanks

Comment: `hana::type_c<Ts>...`? Just a guess.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz That seems to have done the trick. If you make it an answer I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to expand the types with the `hana::type_c` helper:

```
static constexpr auto asSet = hana::make_set(hana::type_c<Ts>...);
```

["Live" on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f31b8b62e5833c77)

Comment: Also, if what you have is a sequence (not a pack), you can use `hana::unpack(sequence, hana::make_set)`.